# Display GUI app on Pi SPI screen

Tags: pi-zero-w-2

I want to kick off a GUI app from the terminal and have it launch on an SPI lcd screen. I already have the app launching in a window form the terminal. But how can i send just that window to the screen, not the whole desktop? Are there any good tutorials for that?

Comment: The command is something like `DISPLAY=:0.1 firefox &` the environment variable DISPLAY set the display that the app will start on.

Answer (score 1):

Is the SPI display connected and configured? Run the command `cat /proc/fb`. Are two frame buffers listed and the second one the SPI display? If so, then the following Python program will display on both in a window and the SPI display.

NOTE: Sometimes after a reboot, the SPI display may be the first frame buffer. I always reboot until it is the second one.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# 1.5inch RGB OLED Display Module 128x128 16-bit High Color SPI
# Interface SSD1351 Driver

import os
os.environ['PYGAME_HIDE_SUPPORT_PROMPT'] = "hide"
import pygame
import subprocess as sp

os.environ['DISPLAY'] = ':0.0'
pygame.init()
pygame.font.init()

#### Get the size of the frame buffer (x, y, bits per pixels). ####
geom = sp.getoutput("fbset -fb /dev/fb1 | grep geometry").split()
xres, yres, bpp = int(geom[1]), int(geom[2]), int(geom[5])
#print(xres, yres, bpp)  # bpp bits per pixel

#### Create surfaces with the same size as the display. ####  
oled = pygame.Surface((xres, yres), 0, bpp)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((xres, yres))

#### Get some fonts and set font size ####
icfont = pygame.font.SysFont('inconsolata', 22)
djfont = pygame.font.SysFont('dejavusans', 20)
pbfont = pygame.font.SysFont('pibotolt', 16)
nsfont = pygame.font.SysFont('notoserif', 20)
llfont = pygame.font.SysFont('linuxlibertinedisplayo', 20)
bsfont = pygame.font.SysFont('bitstreamverasansmono', 18)
#print(pygame.font.get_fonts())

#### Define refresh SPI frame buffer ####
def refresh():
    fd = open("/dev/fb1","wb")
    fd.write(oled.get_buffer())
    fd.close()

#### Populate the surface with objects to be displayed ####
pygame.draw.rect(oled,(255,255,0),(4,22,38,42))
oled.blit(icfont.render('Hello!', True, (255,255,255)), (2, 1))
oled.blit(djfont.render('Hello!', True, (255,64,64)), (56, 2))
oled.blit(pbfont.render('Hello!', True, (128,255,128)), (56, 26))
oled.blit(nsfont.render('Hello!', True, (128,128,255)), (56, 46))
oled.blit(llfont.render('Hello!', True, (255,128,255)), (56, 74))
oled.blit(bsfont.render('Hello!', True, (255,255,255)), (56, 96))

#### Blit the surface to the screen ####
screen.blit(oled,(0,0))

#### Update the the displays ####
pygame.display.flip()
refresh()

pygame.event.clear()
x = 1
while x:
    event = pygame.event.wait()
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT or event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        oled.fill((0, 0, 0))
        refresh()
        x = 0
        pygame.quit()
```